# Calculate percentage change at every variation of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to calculate the `df['col4']= df.pct_change()` of `col2` at every variation of `col3`. I calculate by hand `col4` in order to explain better my problem. Thanks

| DataCreazione | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-17 00:00:00 | 10.55 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-02-17 00:00:00 | 12.55 | 0 | 0.1895 |
| 2021-10-05 00:00:00 | 14.55 | 0 | 0.1593 |
| 2021-10-05 00:00:00 | 10.55 | 0 | -0.2749 |
| 2021-09-15 00:00:00 | 9.45 | 1 | 0 |
| 2021-10-02 00:00:00 | 8.65 | 1 | -0.08465 |
| 2021-10-05 00:00:00 | 8.65 | 1 | 0 |

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, you want to run the `pct_change()` function on the rows where the value of `col3` is `1`?

Comment: @KunalGehlot `pct_change()` on a `groupby()` of `col3`?

Comment: I think what you need to do is create Hierarchical indexes, where `col3` is your second index. Then run `pct_change()` on every row and reset the change on every change of the second index, I.e. `col3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try

```py
df['out'] = (df.groupby('col3', group_keys=False)
             .apply(lambda g: g['col2'].pct_change())
             .fillna(0))
```

```
print(df)

         DataCreazione   col2  col3     col4       out
0  2021-02-17 00:00:00  10.55     0  0.00000  0.000000
1  2021-02-17 00:00:00  12.55     0  0.18950  0.189573
2  2021-10-05 00:00:00  14.55     0  0.15930  0.159363
3  2021-10-05 00:00:00  10.55     0 -0.27490 -0.274914
4  2021-09-15 00:00:00   9.45     1  0.00000  0.000000
5  2021-10-02 00:00:00   8.65     1 -0.08465 -0.084656
6  2021-10-05 00:00:00   8.65     1  0.00000  0.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I got similar desire like this:

```
df['col5'] = df.groupby(by=['col3']).col2.pct_change().fillna(0)


DataCreazione            col2  col3     col4      col5
0  2021-02-17 00:00:00  10.55     0         0  0.000000
1  2021-02-17 00:00:00  12.55     0    0.1895  0.189573
2  2021-10-05 00:00:00  14.55     0    0.1593  0.159363
3  2021-10-05 00:00:00  10.55     0   -0.2749 -0.274914
4  2021-09-15 00:00:00   9.45     1         0  0.000000
5  2021-10-02 00:00:00   8.65     1  -0.08465 -0.084656
6  2021-10-05 00:00:00   8.65     1         0  0.000000
```